# Creating two tables in two different classes for sqllite - android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am creating 2 tables in the same sqlite database (Meaning both tables having same database name and helper name in both the classes) but in two different classes, when i run for first time, A is giving creation success and B creation failure, however when i rerun it, even A is giving failure. In the create table method, i am using version = 1, for A and version = 2 for B. Is this the cause?? I am using same database name and handler names in both the classes. Please suggest where am i going wrong!